# Can I add custom functions to gcalctool?

Tags: gcalctool

I've noticed an f(x) button in calculator's (gcalctool) advanced mode. The button opens a drop-down list with some predefined functions. Is it possible to define more?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you press F1 and read the [help page about functions](http://library.gnome.org/users/gcalctool/stable/functions.html.en) it says: “GCalctool does not support user-defined functions.”, so I guess the answer is *no*.

Of course you can propose additions to the program's developer(s) or write your own patch to add more functions.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see an f(x) button, but in scientific mode there is a 'Fun' button with a drop down list. Initially this is empty except for an 'Edit Functions...' button. If you click this, you can edit the functions 0 to 9.

If you do something like this:

[image: Edit Functions],

selecting F0 from the function list will add2 to your answer. For more details, see the Gcalctool help:

[image: help]

There doesn't seem to be a way to define a function in the traditional sense (where you define f(x) to be a transformation of x into another value)

Comment: Is this in Lucid?  GCalcTool in Maverick doesn't have all this...

Comment: Right, seems like the Scientific Mode was removed...

Comment: :o I didn't know they removed the scientific mode. Oh well, this answer is still valid for <= Lucid.

Comment: No fun in my calc :-( See screenshot I've added to illustrate the question. And there's no 'Edit Functions...' inside 'f(x)'.

Comment: For some reason they removed this feature in 10.10 :(

Answer (score 0):

Nope, but you can install [Qalculate](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/qalculate), it's a nice calculator with a lot of options and functions.

Here a screencapture.
[image]

Comment: However good an alternative calculator may be (I prefer ExtCalc), It does not answer the question to suggest it.

Comment: *looks at screenshot* MY EYES

Comment: The screenshot is the official screenshot, it's not my fault (I know, it's horrible).